# asp:TreeView with XPFileExplorer setting images

Tags: c#, asp.net, treeview

I have used a Treeview with **ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"**  I have created a loop to populate a set of directories into TreeNodes, into the treenodecollection that is the Treeviews nodes.  This works and gives me a treeview that represents the hierarchy of the directories.  However, the icons are all wrong.  Some are computer icons, some are text file icons, some are folder icons.  My question is how can I get them to all be folder icons.  I see there is a way to set the ImageUrl on the TreeNodes, however I don't want to make up my own images.  I much prefer to use the images supplied by **ImageSet="XPFileExplorer"**  Here is the asp and the methods I'm using for making the nodes.

```
<asp:TreeView ID="TreeViewfilelist" runat="server" 
            onload="TreeViewfilelist_Load" ImageSet="XPFileExplorer" 
        NodeIndent="15">
            <HoverNodeStyle Font-Underline="True" ForeColor="#6666AA" />
            <NodeStyle Font-Names="Tahoma" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="Black" 
                HorizontalPadding="2px" NodeSpacing="0px" VerticalPadding="2px" />
            <ParentNodeStyle Font-Bold="False" />
            <SelectedNodeStyle BackColor="#B5B5B5" Font-Underline="False" 
                HorizontalPadding="0px" VerticalPadding="0px" />
</asp:TreeView>
```

**Call onload**

```
TreeNodeCollection main = TreeViewfilelist.Nodes;
makemainNodes(main, dir);
```

**Methods:**

```
protected void makemainNodes(TreeNodeCollection treec, System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in directory.GetDirectories())
        {               
            TreeNode child = new TreeNode(g.Name);                
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(g.FullName);
            makesubNodes(child, dir);
            treec.Add(child);
        } 
    }
protected void makesubNodes(TreeNode treec, System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory)
    {
        foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in directory.GetDirectories())
        {              
            TreeNode child = new TreeNode(g.Name);
            System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(g.FullName);
            makesubNodes(child, dir);
            treec.ChildNodes.Add(child);
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any way to change all the icons to folder icons using the builtin ImageSet="XPFileExplorer."  Instead I created my own image of folder.png, added to an Images folder within my project and as I create the nodes for the tree I use

```
child.ImageUrl = "~/Images/folder.png";
```

In the example above,

```
protected void makemainNodes(TreeNodeCollection treec, System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in directory.GetDirectories())
    {               
        TreeNode child = new TreeNode(g.Name);                
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(g.FullName);
        child.ImageUrl = "~/Images/folder.png";            
        makesubNodes(child, dir);
        treec.Add(child);
    } 
}

protected void makesubNodes(TreeNode treec, System.IO.DirectoryInfo directory)
{
    foreach (System.IO.DirectoryInfo g in directory.GetDirectories())
    {              
        TreeNode child = new TreeNode(g.Name);
        System.IO.DirectoryInfo dir = new System.IO.DirectoryInfo(g.FullName);
        child.ImageUrl = "~/Images/folder.png";
        makesubNodes(child, dir);
        treec.ChildNodes.Add(child);
    } 
}
```